# Tram tickets in Bonn

Tags: public-transport, germany, bonn

I need to take a very early tram tomorrow and I just need to buy which is so called EinzelTicket Erwachsene (1 trip, 1 person) for tariff zone 1b (shortest distance within the city). The problem is I couldn't see any ticket machines on the platform. What should I do?

I need to take the tram (well bus stop seems a bit far) Burbacher Straße 36 to Bonn Hbf around 10am. I know I can walk but I have a huge luggage.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The tram (as any in Bonn) will have a ticket machine inside but be aware that it only takes coins. If you take a bus you can pay at the driver. The price at the moment is 2.80€ for a single trip.

You can also buy ticket beforehand at any of [these shops](http://www.swb-busundbahn.de/service/externe-verkaufsstellen.html) or [these counters](http://www.swb-busundbahn.de/service/servicecenter.html) but most (if not all) are likely closed in the evening.

Do **not** buy a ticket from a machine if you don't plan to travel immediately as tickets from a machine are directly validated.